# Extracting Ajax return data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I have done jQuery and Ajax, but I am not able to get the response into a Div element. This is the code:

**Index.html**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data:"id="+id ,
    success: function(html){
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
```

It is receiving the response to my `<div id="response"></div>`.

The `ajax.php` returns following code to the `index.html` file:

```
<div id ="one"> OneVal </div>
<div id ="sub"> SubVal </div>
```

Will I able to extract the OneVal and Subval into a variable, and how can I extract "OneVal" and "SubVal", instead of above response?

Comment: var plz=$response.find('#title').text();
alert(plz);
It Throws Null Values ,Should I need to Do any other thing to Get Values

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can use `.filter` on a jQuery object that was created from the response:

```
success: function(data){
    //Create jQuery object from the response HTML.
    var $response=$(data);

    //Query the jQuery object for the values
    var oneval = $response.filter('#one').text();
    var subval = $response.filter('#sub').text();
}
```

Comment: I am a jQuery novice, but I needed var $response(data.d) to get this to work. **added the .d**

Comment: For me, i tweaked the above to use .html() instead of .text() b/c i needed to retrieve the full html instead of just a text string. i.e. `var oneval = $response.filter('#one').html();`

Comment: if (data.d) { data = data.d }

Answer (score 17):

Change the `.find` to `.filter`...

Comment: Spent 30mins playing with this before I saw your follow up here. Edited to include filter :D

Comment: Can you give an explanation why you can't use .find() here? I've tested it and indeed you get result when using .filter() but not when using .find()..

Comment: @Yves Van Broekhoven because there is no wrapping root element so the jquery object contains multiple root nodes which you have to filter

Answer (score 12):

I have noticed that your success function has the parameter "html", and you are trying to add "data" to your elements `html()`... Change it so these both match:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data:"id="+id ,
    success: function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `json` like the following example.

[PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

`$array` is array data, and the jQuery code is:

```
$.get("period/education/ajaxschoollist.php?schoolid="+schoolid, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    var a = JSON.parse(responseTxt);
    $("#hideschoolid").val(a.schoolid);
    $("#section_id").val(a.section_id);
    $("#schoolname").val(a.schoolname);
    $("#country_id").val(a.country_id);
    $("#state_id").val(a.state_id);
}
```

Comment: What about the ending "}"?

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the jQuery **context** parameter. [Link to docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> Selector Context
>
> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function

Therefore you could also have:

```
success: function(data){
    var oneval = $('#one',data).text();
    var subval = $('#sub',data).text();
}
```