# Returning data is not working in jQuery using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, return, extract

I have developed code with Ajax and jQuery. I have got a response from my.php, and I have
tried to extract the values of the response. Here the code (HTML):

#### My.php

```
?php
    echo '<div id="title">My Title </div>';
    echo '<div id="message"> My message </div>';
?>
```

I try to extract the title and message so my code is below.

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("OK");

                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "my.php",
                    cache:false ,
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#response").html(data);
                        var $response = $(data);
                        var oneval = $response.find('#title').text();
                        var subval = $response.find('#message').text();
                        alert(oneval);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="response">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...

The problem is when I tried to alert, it is not working. What is wrong with this logic? Should I use another function to extract the title and message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, go to http://jsbin.com/udige/ and you can see it working.

The key is using `.filter`, not .find as the two divs are root elements in the response. My mistake.

Basically do the following:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#response").html(data);
    var $response = $(data);
    var oneval = $response.filter('#title').text();
    var subval = $response.filter('#message').text();
    alert(oneval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response is coming back as you wrote it then the code which I gave you will work.

You really need to learn how to use a debugger ([Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29)) and put breakpoints into your code so you can use the console to test selectors and look at the values of variables, etc.
Also you should really have responded to the original question and answer that I gave rather than opening a whole new question especially since you have not even cross referenced your original.

Comment: I done Your example with as you pointed out, When i try to alert the value, It simply throghs null message,Firebug says sucess.Still i not able to alert it how to do it ?

Comment: Can you put breakpoints inside the success function and establish exactly what data is in the response.

Comment: if not can you put this live and link the url so I can help

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @newfurniturey great thanks, did the fact the answer is 5.5 yrs old pass you by?

Comment: @redsquare I meant no disrespect, this answer showed up in the review queue and the comment is auto-added when flagging (based on which flag is chosen). When reviewing/flagging, I only take into account the question/answer content - not the age, vote ratio, user, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead:

```
var oneval = $("#response #title").text();
var subval = $("#response #message").text();
```

Comment: Is the div actually filling with the content you are sending back?  That is, can you see 'My Title' and 'My Message'?

Comment: Michael, #response wont work as seen as there is not element with an id of response!

Comment: not in the data returned hence it wont work....bah.....he is messing up his questions see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery#400232 also. Anyway there is no benefit or need to run two id selectors side by side....

Comment: I suspect his return data is not as he says, he could really do with getting firebug installed and seeing what is actually happening

Comment: It doesn't need to be in the returned data... notice that I'm using the root $ operator...  not on $(response) as he indicates.  The side-by-side selectors specifies that you want the 'title' id tag that is a descendant of the 'response' tag.  There is a benefit - I use it all the time.

Comment: I often get data that is html formatted, and then bind events (usually click) to elements that are returned in this manner.  Important thing is to do it in the result handler.

Comment: michael, trust me there is no benefit, it is slower than using just 1 id selector....in your case it has to filter to a subset first instead of using getElementById

Comment: Although you are correct, the #response isn't necessary...   He could probably just $('#title') and $('#message') in the handler.

Comment: simple test case here to illustrate the non benefit (slowness)
http://pastebin.me/495b37682a9e3

Comment: But only in this simple case where there is only one parent element...   I have many cases where I load similar content into different elements.  Then you would have to use the parent selector.

Comment: his original question asked how he can get those values without inserting into the dom, so i took the response and found the two elements and put them into vars. he seems to have changed track by inserting into the html first...

Comment: Michael, id's are unique, you never need a parent selector when using an id selector. never!

Comment: You're concerned about a 0.4ms difference??

Comment: Re: unique id's...  good point!  I usually end up using class tags to identify these...   it's 4am.  :)

Comment: just making a point, lots of 0.4 ms add up.....why make things ineffecient for the hell of it