# jquery ajax fetch only one div block from other page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a succeed ajax request that can download the whole html contents, now I only need to get a div tag which contains id "data-today".

How to code such a script?

Comment: @user , did you append that html to dom already ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this SOq:

- [Extracting Ajax return data in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery)

Something along these lines:

```
success: function(data) {
   //create jquery object from the response html
   var $response=$(data);
   //query the jq object for the values
   var dataToday = $response.find('#data-today').text();
}
```

Comment: kool , this will take care eventhough html is not attached to DOM..+1///

Answer (score 2):

`$('#data-today').html()`  if you want all the html // this out puts

if you want text inside it

```
$('#data-today').text() // this gives hello how are you
```

.text() gives the text in between html

```
<div> hello how are you </div>
```

Comment: @user my answer will work if you append the results to dom already. icyrock answer will get you that div results from the response.