# HTML opening tags missing from extracted part of AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax

For some reason all opening HTML tags are missing from an extracted part of AJAX response. Please see code and alert box images below. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
alert(data);
json_response = $(data).find('div#json').text();
alert(json_response);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Are you asking why the second alert is without the html tags?

Comment: Well, you've already got your answer bellow. In short, `text()` returns the textual content of the element without any HTML tags, while `html()` treats the whole content of the element simply as text and returns all of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
json_response = $(data).find('div#json').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your JSON inside an HTML for some reason, but the HTML parser of the browser doesn't know about JSON, so it consides the HTML inside the JSON just to be part of document. And since the slashes are (unneseccarily) escaped it only recognizes the opening and not the closing tags, and since you use `.text()` it gives you the text, but not the HTML lelements it recognize.

Why do you have the JSON inside HTML at all? Don't do that.

And if you believe you have to have it like that, then you'll need to HTML escape the JSON:

```
<div><div id="json">{"twee": "&lt;ol&gt;&lt;li&gt;pro&lt;/li&gt;&lt/ol;li&gt;hallo&lt;/li&gt;&lt;&gt;"}</div></div>
```

Comment: I included JSON (generated with PHP's json_encode function) inside a div to be able to extract it from the AJAX response containing morte than pure JSON >>>> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312141/script-script-code-sent-along-with-json-response

Comment: @DurianNangka It seems to make more sense to put everything into the JSON instead of using a crutch like that.

Comment: You're probably right. Need to remove the Javascript from the PHP generating the JSON code.