# Loading variable from php into javascript continuously

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

I am currently trying to draw some dynamically loaded graphs using google's visualization tools.

I want to pull the data from an sql database. I have a php script (**getnumber.php**) that is capable of doing so.

I am trying to use this php script within my javascript that draws the graphs.

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function drawChart(Z)
  {
    tmpdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    datalist.push(tmpdata);
    datalist[Z].addColumn('string', 'Complete');
    datalist[Z].addRows([['Finished', $.ajax({url:"getnumber.php"})], ['Incomplete', 10]]);
    .
    .
    .
  }
  window.setInterval("drawChart()", 1000);
</script>
```

I realise that this use of $.ajax is completely wrong but I'm stumped!

Comment: What does "is capable of doing so" mean? Does the script return some sort of JSON? Also, have you ever used $ajax in another situation then this?

Comment: No it's the first time I've used it. The php script pulls the data successfully, it's getting it to return it to my javascript that I am having an issue with. 
I was not returning it as JSON. I had just tried to return the php variable. Although I am now realising this probably won't work. If it's any help the variable is just an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using either `$.post()` or `$.get()` functions instead of using the basic ajax one. Anyways, you can manipulate the data in thsoe 3 functions this way

```
$.post('getnumber.php',function(data){
/* Do whatever you want with the data you grabbed from the php page. */
});
```

I'm not sure of what your question is exactly, but I hope this will help you.

Have a nice day!

EDIT: The functions themselves don't contain the data, it is contained into the `function(data){}` portion of the `$.ajax()` call.

Edit2: The `$.ajax();` function has a parameter called `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`which can be used, compared to the two other functions.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Hi thank's for your help. I have now got the script to call this way. 
Within the function I am trying to assign the data to a variable to use elsewhere. However, nothing appears to have been assigned.
`function(data){variable1 = data}`
In what form do I need to return the variable from the php script?

Currently I was just trying `return $max_number` but the javascript picks it up as being empty. Perhaps this return needs to be within a function? Or can it return just from the script.

Comment: Hi, first of all I would appreciate if you could mark the question as solved. Secondly, the `data` variable contains the content of your query result (whatever db you use, mssql,mysql,etc.) take a look at this page for a great ajax example with a php page being called:
http://www.codingcereal.com/2009/09/retrieving-data-using-ajax-jquery/

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following:

```
my_url="dosomething.php";
function getvar() {
  var json = null;
  $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': my_url,
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (data) {
          json = data;
      }
  });
  json = parseInt(json);
  return json;
};
```

With the php script ending with:

`echo json_encode($id_max);`

For some reason I could not get $.post to work. Thanks for the help anyway.