# how to get specific data from ajax response

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a link that sends an ajax request to a particular url with some data. The destination of ajax url do some operation and return the data. Now I have a problem that the ajax response also contain all the html. Some how I cannot disable the layout or html like stuff. Now can you tell me how can I do this task. Is there a rocket scientific way to get a specific data from ajax response.

I have got idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery) that I will send my response in some html element and then I will get that html element. But It looks very bad approach. So far what I have tried is this

```
$.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'ajaxcall','name'=>'shahrukh','id'=>377),'default');?>",
        type: "post",
        data: {car: 'Honda' },

        success: function(data){

           var $response=$(data);

           var oneval = $response.filter('#one').html();
           alert(oneval);
      }});
```

On server end I just do

```
 echo "<div id='one'>Ajax response</div>";
```

Is there any other way to do this... 
By the way it also returns undefined :-(

Best Regards

Comment: Do you mean that you want take only a portion of the returned ajax response?

Comment: @shawndreck yes exactly dear

Comment: can you  change response to json?

Comment: @Rajesh please explain your answer. You I send my response in json and how can I get only json data from whole response?

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax json response

```
$.ajax({


url:"sdsdds.jsp",
dataType:'json',
success:function(jsonDataFrmServer){
alert(jsonDataFrmServer.myCUstomData);
alert(jsonDataFrmServer.whateverContentForHtml);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can always check for the header `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` to detect an ajax request. And then based on that condition you can switch the response's content.

Also if you wish to strip out some html content from the response in your javascript ajax success function, then I could suggest that you wrap the needed response around an html comment. For example: `<!--AjaxResponseStart-->...<!--AjaxResponseEnd-->`. Then it simply becomes just a matter of using some few checks (for undefined) and regex to get only the needed content:

Here is a sample of how you could get the html content from the response:

```
pattern = /[\s\S]*?<\!--AjaxResponseStart-->([\s\S]*)<\!--AjaxResponseEnd-->[\s\S]*/i;
if(str.match(pattern)){
  return reponse.replace(pattern, '$1');    
}
```

Hope you get what I am trying to say.