# How to select the dom which new append

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to select the dom which new append?
Because there can be append not just one time and not the same order, so I thought the only way is when append new dom, then set variable equal this (in `question 1`) , but after append another, then they will both be change.. How to solve this?

also I'm wondering `question 2` why console.log will print `[]` not string?

html

```
<div class="container">
    <!--append to here and insert value from ajax response in .id , each time click button will append new here, insert different id -->
</div>

<div class="button-insert">button</div>

<div class="inser-template">
    <div class="id"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.button-insert').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getlastid',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {getlastid: 'getlastid'},
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response); // ex. 1 or … the value from database field

// question 1 
        // after append another dom, they will both be change to new value from 'response'
        var $newInsert = $('.container').append($('.insert-template').html());
        $newInsert.find($('.id').html(response));

// question 2
        // get []
        // var lastid = $(response);
        // console.log(lastid);  
})
...
```

for question 2
php

```
...
// select db get last id + 1 or
$getlastid = '1';
return $getlastid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, you could do this:

```
$($('.insert-template').html())
    .appendTo('.container')
    .find('.id')
    .html('response');
```

For number 2, I'm not sure what you're expecting. I think your `response` is `'1'`. Creating a jQuery object from that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: it works. thanks so much!!   about question 2 the `response` is what kind of type? if I want to transition to html string put in html, is there only way I should make a html container put in there first then catch again to do what i want??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: if I have to let the `response` data become html string in jquery, how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery   do I have to change like above link make html structure in php return data? is there any other way??

Comment: No, you can generate your own html. You could do `$('<div class="myclass"/>').text(response).appendTo('#someDiv')`, for example.