# Can't filter data from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get new data from `index.php` via AJAX and insert it into an element. Unfortunately, jQuery won't filter the data correctly. I use the same options, that have been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery).

*Corrected version:*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php",
    data: "ajaxGetContent=1",
    success: function(data){
        $(data).filter(".bubble").html();
        $("#bubbles").empty();
        $("#bubbles").append(data);
    }
});
```

When executing this code, this error message shows up in the console:

"Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: *All the requested HTML code*"

Comment: You should not change your original question with things from the answers you get as then the answers will stop making sense. You can add any additions below your original question.

Comment: @jeroen Thank you for your suggestion. I marked the code as corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the filtered data when you add it to your `#bubbles` element. Note that `data` remains unchanged in the first line of your success function.

You probably want something like:

```
success: function(data){
    var filtered_data = $(data).filter(".bubble").html();
    $("#bubbles").empty();
    $("#bubbles").append(filtered_data);
}
```

**Note** that the name of your `url` suggests that you are reloading your whole page with the ajax request and then using only a small part of it. You should make that small part a separate include in your original page and use that script to load using ajax so that you don't have to filter at all.

That would also reduce the amount of data that needs to be sent and the redundant processing that is now done on the server and discarded right away.

Comment: Solution 1: Thank you, I corrected the question, since this didn't solve the problem.

I will try your second solution.

Comment: @SimonMathewson What do you see for the response in the console?

Comment: @SimonMathewson That looks like a javascript error. What is the response from the php script or does that not get executed at all?

Comment: The PHP file echoes the same content it would usually echo, unfiltered.

Comment: @SimonMathewson You should do a `console.log()` of the filtered data to see if that is correct as well. Although a separate file is definitely the better solution...

Comment: Tried that. But it doesn't even `console.log()` the filtered data, probably because of the error before.

Comment: Solution two is, unfortunately, because of various reasons not an option. Any idea why solution one isn't working?

Comment: Apparently, jQuery couldn't filter HTML with content before the `html`, so I removed it. But now, `console.log()` shows that filtered_data equals 

`[prevObject: n.fn.init[54], context: undefined, jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function, selector: ""…]context: undefinedlength: 0prevObject: n.fn.init[54]__proto__: n[0]`