# Null is not an object with AJAX and retrieving partial page

Tags: jquery, ajax

## Could really use some help figuring this out!

I am trying to retrieve a portion of HTML with jQuery but getting an error:

> Null is not an object on

This line causes the error:

```
$("#collection").html(jQuery(html).find('#collection').html());
```

```js
function update_products(ajax_page) {  
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajax_page,
    data: {},
    success: function(html) { 
      $("#collection").html(jQuery(html).find('#collection').html());  
      history.pushState({
        page: ajax_page
      }, "", ajax_page);                  
    }
  }); 
}
```

It's working when retrieving entire page:

```
function update_products(ajax_page) {  
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ajax_page,
    data: {},
    success: function(html) { 
      $("#collection").html(html);  
      history.pushState({
        page: ajax_page
      }, "", ajax_page);                  
    }
  }); 
}
```

I think it has something to do with `jQuery(html).find('#collection').html()`, but I do not know where I am going wrong.

## Error with another version:

> Null is not an object
>   On this line
>   `var $response=$(html);'

```
function update_products(ajax_page) {  
$.ajax({
url: ajax_page,
dateType: 'html',
success: function(html){ 
      //Create jQuery object from the response HTML.
    var $response=$(html);

    //Query the jQuery object for the values
    var collection = $response.filter('#collection').text();

  $("#collection").html(collection);  
     history.pushState({
     page: ajax_page
     }, "", ajax_page);                  
}


});
```

Comment: If you do `console.log(jQuery(html).find('#collection').length)` what do you see?

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: html

Comment: In that case are you sure you've defined `html` in the arguments of the `success` handler?

Comment: How do I check? I am a beginner at Jquery and Javascript/Ajax

Comment: If I understand your question, I think I must have since the other function works. right? or am I wrong? I do know I am passing ajax_page correctly.

Comment: That would seem to be the case, but given the JS you've shown, the `Can't find variable: html` error makes absolutely no sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180200/discussion-between-user2012677-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: Maybe this link would be helpful: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400197/extracting-ajax-return-data-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a previous project I've done similar to the following:

```
$("#collection").load(ajax_page+" #collection", ajax=true, function(){
    history.pushState({
        page: ajax_page
        }, "", ajax_page); 
});
```

Granted, my project didn't have the same IDs and my url wasn't in a variable, it was constant, so I just wrote it in.

I do further work on my project within the returned data, but I put it into a hidden DIV so it's actually part of the page before I manipulate it.  That wouldn't work for you, since the ID would be on the page twice. It's probably possible to do without that, but I didn't fight it to find out.  These days I'd offload the processing that goes into the `#collection` div to a separate script, which is way easier to ajax in when you want it refreshed.

Comment: This seems to work, is there a way to update multiple divs at once so I don't need to call it twice or three times?

Comment: That's what I'm doing on my page, I load the whole thing into a hidden div, but you'll have to do something different if the ID's are going to be on the page multiple times.

Comment: If you can't contain all of your "dynamic" content within a single element, you're going to have to do multiple calls.  The ID's being the same necessitates that.

Comment: The multiple divs I want to update are different ids.  For example, #collection and #filters.  Or do you mean the id from the original page, matching the id of the new ajax page?

Comment: Yes, the id's from the original page and the id's from the ajax page match.  My method was to store the returned data on the page, but you can't reliably have two of the same ID on a page.  You could probably alter the received IDs when you get them, but personally, I'd rather have many smaller requests instead of one larger one.  They work concurrently, and update the page on their own schedule, instead of all at once.  I could see how that may not be ideal for some applications, especially if one or more requests took markedly longer than the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `'html'` as an argument to the success handler.

Comment: sorry did not spot that !

Comment: If I console.log($("#collection").html()), it returns the html

Comment: What is the output of console.log(jQuery(html));

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: html